# threading issues with java swing and web start

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

EDIT: After fixing a few issues, the bigger issue that I am having is being caused by Apache POI which I am using. I am working on figuring that out now. Apparently it is being restricted by the Sandbox.

I'm very new to Swing, and created a small Swing app that I now need to have run via web start. I'm trying to use the FileOpenService and update a Text display. I think I am running into threading issues, because the FileOpenService dialog never appears, and my text display is not getting updated.

I can't really find any examples where they are doing anything different than I am right now.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: I now have the FileOpenService dialog appearing. I changed my main to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

However, I still can't get my display to update. This is where I am doing the update:

```
 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (final String s : Logger.getMessages())
                append(s + "\n");
        }
    };

    try {
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
            r.run();
        else
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
    }
```

and my append method:

```
private void append(Color c, String s) {// throws Exception {
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY,
            StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
    int len = _textPaneLog.getDocument().getLength();
    try {
        _textPaneLog.getDocument().insertString(len, s, aset);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a brief code sample that illustrates what you're doing, nobody could begin to guess where you're going wrong.

Comment: I think I might be able to provide something. Just a few minutes.

Comment: Have you created any new threads? If so... what are they for? If not, what makes you think it is a threading issue? It could just as easily be a typo.

Comment: `FileOpenService` should work on or off the EDT (when on the EDT it behaves as if it were a modal dialog box, in fact it may be implemented using one). It currently displays a dialog box before the file open dialog (nasty, evil UI).

Comment: @Mark I am pretty sure it is a threading issue, because when I step though in the debugger, the code is executed, but I never see anything. No exceptions or any other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having had nothing to do with any of this. In another part of my code right near where I was trying to do this, I was causing an application exit. It was a hold over from something else I was trying out that got missed when I was working on implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling *.openFileDialog(foo,bar) right?

```
FileOpenService fos = (FileOpenService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileOpenService");

FileContents fc = fos.openFileDialog(null, null);
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but until you update your question with source I can't think of much else.